# Xcode building differently on VM vs native install

Tags: xcode, virtual-machine, macos-sierra

I’m completely stumped by this one, and hoping a SO user with more Xcode experience can enlighten me as to what’s happening with my application build, or how I should go about debugging the problem.

I have an older application that uses the (now depreciated) QTKit library to interface with USB video sources. I wanted to see if it would build successfully on the macOS 10.12 beta.

I downloaded the beta and installed it, along with Xcode 7.3.1 inside a VMWare virtual machine. After a bug was resolved (more about this below), the application built and ran successfully.

Next I installed macOS 10.12 into its own partition, and installed the same version of Xcode. I copied over the Xcode project files from the VM. This time, when I built the application, it shows a blank screen where the webcam image should be.

A few additional facts:

- When I move the app built inside the VM to the partition OS install, it continues to function properly.
- When the application is built inside the VM, the console logs: “Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer. Core Image is now using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow"
- I retain and release CIImages in a few places. When I first built the app in the VM, there was an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error due to an image being referenced after it was released.  Also, in the VM build, if the image instances are not released, it results in a huge memory leak. In the partition build, I can remove the code retaining and releasing the images. No leak occurs, and no access errors happen.

Why do I get different results depending on whether the application is built inside a VM, vs a native OS install?

Answer (score 0):

> When I move the app built inside the VM to the partition OS install, it continues to function properly.
>   ...
>   Why do I get different results depending on whether the application is built inside a VM, vs a native OS install?

I do not know your specific case, I can say I get the same results when an application is built in either native or virtual environments.

I have so far identified there to be an issue with accelerated OpenGL virtualisation in 10.12. Though I have not had a machine I can test that the behaviour is not consistent with hardware.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000381/608945 for how to detect if the hardware accelerated OpenGL renderer is available. I tried this with 10.11 (hardware), it returned `true`, with 10.12 (in Parallels, virtual), this returns `false`.

I feel like if there is a use case given the application is to be used in a virtual environment, when hardware acceleration is not available, then it should be handled appropriately.